Quadratics in form
I am trying to solve $x^6 - 10x^3 + 16$ and have all the book solutions except one which is given as $$\frac{\sqrt[3]{2} \pm i\sqrt[6]{108}}{2}$$ I know it involves the difference of $2$ cubes $x^3 - 2 = 0$ but have trouble as $2$ is not a perfect cube. I suspect the book solution is incorrect as a $6$th root becomes involved, but I am not sure. Any help is much appreciated.
PaulK

Hint: nobody said the difference of squares/cubes/whatever formulas required perfect powers.

Per Sean Roberson's hint.  As $x^3 -a^3 = (x-a)(x^2 + ax + a^3)$ then $x^3 -b = (x-\sqrt[3] b)(x^2 +\sqrt[3]b x + \sqrt[3]{b}^2$.  ...  Or... to be snarky $2$ is a cube.  It is $(\sqrt[3]2)^3$.  It's just not a perfect cube.

Welcome to MathSE.  This MathJax tutorial explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Assuming you're trying to solve $x^6-10x^3+16=0$, we may firstly observe that the powers of $x$ are all multiples of three, and so we may have a substitution $a=x^3$ and solve for $a$ first. We have:
\begin{align}
x^6-10x^3+16 &=0 \\
(x^3)^2-10x^3+16&=0\\
a^2-10a+16&=0\\
(a-2)(a-8)&=0\\
a&=2 \quad\text{ or } \quad a=8
\end{align}
Thus, we have $x^3=2$ or $x^3=8$. We now have two options, factorising the LHS (left hand side) of the original equation through the difference of cubes formula, or using the method of Euler's form for complex numbers.
Method 1: Factorising the LHS
As $(x^3-2)(x^3-8)=0$, we may do some further factorisation using the formula for the difference of cubes: $$ x^3-y^3=(x-y)(x^2+xy+y^2) $$
We can substitute $y=\sqrt[3]{2}$ and $y=\sqrt[3]{8}=2$ into the above formula to find the factorisations of $x^3-2$ and $x^3-8$. This gives us $$(x-\sqrt[3]{2})(x^2+\sqrt[3]{2}x+\sqrt[3]{4})(x-2)(x^2+2x+4)=0$$
Any of these four terms can equal zero for the RHS to be zero. If the first term is equal to zero, we have $x=\sqrt[3]{2}$. If the third term is equal to zero, we have $x=2$. To find $x$ if the second or fourth term is equal to zero, we may use the quadratic formula.
If the second term is equal to zero, we have
\begin{align}
x&=\frac{-\sqrt[3]{2}\pm \sqrt{(\sqrt[3]{2})^2-4\times1\times\sqrt[3]{4}}}{2\times 1}\\
&=\frac{-\sqrt[3]{2}\pm\sqrt{-3\sqrt[3]{4}}}{2}\\
&=\frac{-\sqrt[3]{2}\pm \sqrt{3}\sqrt[3]{2}i}{2}\\
&=\frac{-\sqrt[3]{2}\pm \sqrt[6]{108}i}{2}
\end{align}
If the fourth term is equal to zero, we have
\begin{align}
x&=\frac{-2\pm \sqrt{2^2-4\times1\times4}}{2\times1}\\
&=\frac{-2\pm \sqrt{-12}}{2}\\
&=-1\pm \sqrt{3}i
\end{align}
We have all six solutions now.
Method 2: Using Roots of Unity
If $x^3=2$, we have $x^3 = 2e^{2k\pi i}$, as every positive real number will have an argument of zero, but after cube rooting the RHS (right hand side), the exponent will be a third of the original, which is why we need the $2k\pi$ instead of $0$ for all three cube roots. We have that $$x=2^\frac13 e^{\frac23k\pi i}$$
We only need to go through $k=0,1,2$, as $k\geq3$ would give a result that is the same as one of the values for $k=0,1,2$, because $e^{2k\pi i}=1$ for any $k\in \mathbb{Z}$.
We have the solutions $x=\sqrt[3]{2}$, $x=\sqrt[3]{2}e^{\frac23\pi i}=\sqrt[3]{2}\left(-\frac12+\frac{\sqrt3}{2}i\right)$ and $x=\sqrt[3]{2}e^{\frac43\pi i}=\sqrt[3]{2}\left(-\frac12-\frac{\sqrt3}{2}i\right)$.
We may use a similar approach if $x^3=8$. We will obtain the solutions of $x=2$, $x=2\left(-\frac12+\frac{\sqrt3}{2}i\right)=-1+\sqrt3i$ and $x=2\left(-\frac12-\frac{\sqrt3}{2}i\right)=-1-\sqrt3i$.
We may check our results with the first method and see that we have obtained the same answers.

$$\begin{align*} 
x^6-10x^3+16=0 \\
\implies(x^3)^2-8x^3-2x^3+16=0 \\
\implies x^3(x^3-8)-2(x^3-8)=0 \\
\implies(x^3-8)(x^3-2)=0 \\
\implies[x^3-(2)^3][x^3-(\sqrt[3]2)^3)]=0 \\
\implies(x-2)(x^2+2x+4)(x-\sqrt[3]2)(x^2+\sqrt[3]2 x+(\sqrt[3]2)^2)=0
\end{align*}$$
Hence you get 2 linear and 2 quadratic factors w.r.t $x$. You can solve them on your own from here I guess?

$x^3 -2 =0\implies x^3 = 2$.
There  is one real cube root of $2$ (namely $\sqrt[3] 2$) and two complex roots.
If you do not know how to find roots of unity with polar coordinates we can find the complex roots by noting $x^3 - a^3= (x-a)(x^2 + ax + a^2)$ so
$x^3 -2 = (x-\sqrt[3]2) (x^2 + \sqrt[3]2 x + \sqrt[3]2^2)=0$
So $x = \sqrt[3]2$ or $x^2 +\sqrt [3]2x + \sqrt[3]2^2 =0$ so
$x =\frac {-\sqrt[3]2 \pm \sqrt{\sqrt[3]2^2 -4\sqrt[3]2^2}}2=$
$\frac  {-\sqrt[3]2 \pm\sqrt{-3\sqrt[3]2^2}}2=$
$\frac {-\sqrt[3]2 \pm i\sqrt 3\sqrt[3]2}2$
We can rewrite $\sqrt 3 \sqrt[3]2$ as $\sqrt[6]{3^3\cdot 2^2}=\sqrt[6]{108}$ if we want.
......
If you do know how to find roots of unity we know the three cube roots of $2$ are:
$2 = 2 e^{2k\pi i}$ so the cube roots are
$2^{\frac 13} e^{\frac 23k\pi i}=$
$2^{\frac 13}(\cos \frac 23k\pi + i \sin \frac 23k\pi)$ for $i=0,1,2$
Now $\frac 23\pi = 120^\circ$ so this values are
$2^{\frac 13}, 2^{\frac 13}(-\frac 12 \pm \frac {\sqrt 3}2i)$.
.....
This is a standard procedure.  If you have $x^n - a = 0$ the $n$ roots are $\sqrt[n]a, \omega\sqrt[n]a, \omega^2\sqrt[n]a, \omega^3\sqrt[n]a,...., \omega^{n-1}\sqrt[n]a$ where $\omega$ is a principle root or unity:  $\omega= e^{\frac {2\pi}n i} = \cos \frac {2\pi}n + i\sin\frac {2\pi}n$, and $\omega^k = e^{\frac {2k\pi}n i} = \cos\frac{2k\pi}n + i\sin\frac {2k\pi}n$.

Nice approach! However, I think that $\frac23\pi = 120^\circ$, and not $60^\circ$

Didn't I ... argh... well, I thought one thing and typed the other.

To make it easier
we can substitute $x=x^3$
$x^2-10x+16=0 \iff (x-8)(x-2)=0$
$x=0 \lor x=2$
substituting back we get
$x^3=8 \lor x^3=2 $
For $x^3=8 \iff x=2 , x=-\sqrt[3]{-1},x=2(-1)^{2/3}$
For $x^3=2 \iff x=-\sqrt[3]{-2}, x=\sqrt[3]{2}, x= (-1)^{2/3} \sqrt[3]{2}$

$x=x^3$ is a really bad substitution. Any other variable would be great
